# Why do I sometimes fully heal at the end of combat?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

At first I thought I was crazy, but I've been keeping an eye out for it and it definitely happens on really rare occasions. I'll be fighting some enemies and when the battle ends, my life bar fills itself back up to full. In my last 2 hours of play or so, I've only seen it happen 3 times.

> - I did not level.
> - I don't have any gear that leeches health.
> - I don't have any abilities that leech health.
> - I did not accidentally drink a potion.
> - I wasn't in or just coming out of Reckoning mode.
> - In at least the most recent occasion, I had no blessings on me.

Anyone have any idea what might be triggering this?

Comment: I'm glad I'm not going crazy! I thought something was afoot.

Comment: What skills do you have active? Are you Might, Finesse or Sorcery focused? What Fate card do you have activated?

Comment: Level 6, finesse abilities, skills are detect hidden, lockpicking, stealth, and mercantilism. I can assure you that none of my abilities are doing it unless they cause some hidden healing not listed in their description.

Comment: I haven't seen this happen again since VERY early in the game.

Comment: Maybe just a bug?

Comment: Were you under the effects of the first shrine's blessing? I believe it regenerates health, though not instantly.

Comment: Nope, no blessings at all. Possibly a bug. I'd think I was insane if @RavenDreamer hadn't confirmed.

Comment: The game *has* been patched since you asked this question...

Comment: I haven't seen this on the PS3

Answer (score 2):

If you have death's touch active you have 15% chance to get 20 health.
its a blessing

Comment: What is "Death's Touch"?

Comment: @Marcelo Its a blessing, a temporary effect caused by clicking on religious statues. You can have one active at a time. They are equivalent to the blessings in Skyrim received from amulets and statues, or the buffs received by clicking on obelisks in Diablo.